# packets are filtered via bridge using namespaced network card

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, bridge, vlan

trying to make local networking experiment, and unable to ping from within the namespaced network.

I'm using Fedora 37.

```bash
Linux dmitry-desktop 6.1.18-200.fc37.x86_64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Sat Mar 11 16:09:14 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

#### I'm getting the following error

```bash
➜ sudo ip netns exec netns-test0 ping 10.10.10.11
PING 10.10.10.11 (10.10.10.11) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.10.10.1 icmp_seq=1 Packet filtered
From 10.10.10.1 icmp_seq=2 Packet filtered
From 10.10.10.1 icmp_seq=3 Packet filtered
```

#### setup

```bash
➜ sudo ip netns add netns-test0                             
➜ sudo ip netns add netns-test1
➜ ls -la /var/run/netns
total 0
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root   80 Mar 22 13:42 .
drwxr-xr-x. 63 root root 1.7K Mar 22 12:55 ..
-r--r--r--.  1 root root    0 Mar 22 13:42 netns-test0
-r--r--r--.  1 root root    0 Mar 22 13:42 netns-test1

➜ sudo ip link add eth00 type veth peer name eth01           
➜ sudo ip link add eth10 type veth peer name eth11 
➜ sudo ip link set eth00 up                       
➜ sudo ip link set eth01 up
➜ sudo ip link set eth01 netns netns-test0
➜ sudo ip link set eth11 netns netns-test1
➜ sudo ip netns exec netns-test0 ip link set lo up
➜ sudo ip netns exec netns-test0 ip link set eth01 up


➜ sudo ip netns exec netns-test0 ip addr 10.10.10.10/24 dev eth01
Command "10.10.10.10/24" is unknown, try "ip address help".

➜ sudo ip netns exec netns-test0 ip addr add 10.10.10.10/24 dev eth01
➜ sudo ip netns exec netns-test1 ip link set lo up                  
➜ sudo ip netns exec netns-test1 ip link set eth11 up               
➜ sudo ip netns exec netns-test1 ip addr add 10.10.10.11/24 dev eth11
➜ sudo ip link add name br0 type bridge
➜ sudo ip addr add 10.10.10.1/24 brd + dev br0 
➜ sudo ip link set br0 up                     

➜ sudo ip link set eth00 master br0
➜ sudo ip link set eth10 master br0

➜ sudo bridge link show br0        
20: eth00@if19: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 master br0 state forwarding priority 32 cost 2 
22: eth10@if21: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 master br0 state forwarding priority 32 cost 2 

➜ sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i br0 -j ACCEPT
➜ sudo ip link set eth00 master br0
```

so from the root namespace I can ping all devices and br0.

```bash
➜ ping 10.10.10.1
PING 10.10.10.1 (10.10.10.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.10.10.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.038 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.10.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.057 ms


➜ ping 10.10.10.10
PING 10.10.10.10 (10.10.10.10) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.10.10.10: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.047 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.10.10: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.060 ms


➜ ping 10.10.10.11
PING 10.10.10.11 (10.10.10.11) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.10.10.11: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.049 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.10.11: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.053 ms
```

but if I start pings from within the namespaced network - I get packet filtered.

```bash
➜ sudo ip netns exec netns-test0 ping 10.10.10.10
PING 10.10.10.10 (10.10.10.10) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.10.10.10: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.021 ms

➜ sudo ip netns exec netns-test0 ping 10.10.10.1 
PING 10.10.10.1 (10.10.10.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.10.10.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.063 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.10.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.070 ms

➜ sudo ip netns exec netns-test0 ping 10.10.10.11
PING 10.10.10.11 (10.10.10.11) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.10.10.1 icmp_seq=1 Packet filtered
From 10.10.10.1 icmp_seq=2 Packet filtered
From 10.10.10.1 icmp_seq=3 Packet filtered

➜ sudo ip netns exec netns-test1 ping 10.10.10.11
PING 10.10.10.11 (10.10.10.11) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.10.10.11: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.018 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.10.11: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.033 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.10.11: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.036 ms

➜ sudo ip netns exec netns-test1 ping 10.10.10.1 
PING 10.10.10.1 (10.10.10.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.10.10.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.061 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.10.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.075 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.10.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.075 ms

took 2s 
➜ sudo ip netns exec netns-test1 ping 10.10.10.10
PING 10.10.10.10 (10.10.10.10) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.10.10.1 icmp_seq=1 Packet filtered
From 10.10.10.1 icmp_seq=2 Packet filtered
From 10.10.10.1 icmp_seq=3 Packet filtered
From 10.10.10.1 icmp_seq=4 Packet filtered

took 3s 
✗  sudo ip netns exec netns-test1 ping 8.8.8.8    
ping: connect: Network is unreachable


➜ sudo ip netns exec netns-test0 ping 8.8.8.8
ping: connect: Network is unreachable

➜ sudo ip -all netns exec ip route                             

netns: netns-test1
10.10.10.0/24 dev eth11 proto kernel scope link src 10.10.10.11 

netns: netns-test0
10.10.10.0/24 dev eth01 proto kernel scope link src 10.10.10.10 


➜ sudo ip -all netns exec ip route add default via 10.10.10.1

netns: netns-test1
netns: netns-test0

➜ sudo ip -all netns exec ip route                           

netns: netns-test1
default via 10.10.10.1 dev eth11 
10.10.10.0/24 dev eth11 proto kernel scope link src 10.10.10.11 

netns: netns-test0
default via 10.10.10.1 dev eth01 
10.10.10.0/24 dev eth01 proto kernel scope link src 10.10.10.10 

➜ sudo ip netns exec netns-test0 ping 8.8.8.8              
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.10.10.1 icmp_seq=1 Packet filtered
From 10.10.10.1 icmp_seq=2 Packet filtered
From 10.10.10.1 icmp_seq=3 Packet filtered
```

my iptables config

```
➜ _ iptables -L -n -v
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   95  7810 DOCKER-USER  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   95  7810 DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   13  1226 ACCEPT     all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 DOCKER     all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   15   956 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 !docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   67  5628 ACCEPT     all  --  br0    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0            all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0            all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0            all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0            all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0            all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0            all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  br0    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  br0    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   15   956 DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  docker0 !docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   95  7810 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   15   956 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   95  7810 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

firewalld:

```
➜ firewall-cmd --list-all    
FedoraWorkstation (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: br0 ens1f1 eth01 eth11 vpn0
  sources: 
  services: dhcpv6-client mdns samba-client ssh
  ports: 1025-65535/udp 1025-65535/tcp
  protocols: 
  forward: no
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

#### sudo nft list ruleset

```bash
table inet firewalld {
    ct helper helper-netbios-ns-udp {
        type "netbios-ns" protocol udp
        l3proto ip
    }

    chain mangle_PREROUTING {
        type filter hook prerouting priority mangle + 10; policy accept;
        jump mangle_PREROUTING_ZONES
    }

    chain mangle_PREROUTING_POLICIES_pre {
        jump mangle_PRE_policy_allow-host-ipv6
    }

    chain mangle_PREROUTING_ZONES {
        iifname "br0" goto mangle_PRE_FedoraWorkstation
        iifname "eth11" goto mangle_PRE_FedoraWorkstation
        iifname "eth01" goto mangle_PRE_FedoraWorkstation
        iifname "vpn0" goto mangle_PRE_FedoraWorkstation
        iifname "ens1f1" goto mangle_PRE_FedoraWorkstation
        iifname "docker0" goto mangle_PRE_docker
        goto mangle_PRE_FedoraWorkstation
    }

    chain mangle_PREROUTING_POLICIES_post {
    }

    chain nat_PREROUTING {
        type nat hook prerouting priority dstnat + 10; policy accept;
        jump nat_PREROUTING_ZONES
    }

    chain nat_PREROUTING_POLICIES_pre {
        jump nat_PRE_policy_allow-host-ipv6
    }

    chain nat_PREROUTING_ZONES {
        iifname "br0" goto nat_PRE_FedoraWorkstation
        iifname "eth11" goto nat_PRE_FedoraWorkstation
        iifname "eth01" goto nat_PRE_FedoraWorkstation
        iifname "vpn0" goto nat_PRE_FedoraWorkstation
        iifname "ens1f1" goto nat_PRE_FedoraWorkstation
        iifname "docker0" goto nat_PRE_docker
        goto nat_PRE_FedoraWorkstation
    }

    chain nat_PREROUTING_POLICIES_post {
    }

    chain nat_POSTROUTING {
        type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat + 10; policy accept;
        jump nat_POSTROUTING_ZONES
    }

    chain nat_POSTROUTING_POLICIES_pre {
    }

    chain nat_POSTROUTING_ZONES {
        oifname "br0" goto nat_POST_FedoraWorkstation
        oifname "eth11" goto nat_POST_FedoraWorkstation
        oifname "eth01" goto nat_POST_FedoraWorkstation
        oifname "vpn0" goto nat_POST_FedoraWorkstation
        oifname "ens1f1" goto nat_POST_FedoraWorkstation
        oifname "docker0" goto nat_POST_docker
        goto nat_POST_FedoraWorkstation
    }

    chain nat_POSTROUTING_POLICIES_post {
    }

    chain nat_OUTPUT {
        type nat hook output priority -90; policy accept;
        jump nat_OUTPUT_POLICIES_pre
        jump nat_OUTPUT_POLICIES_post
    }

    chain nat_OUTPUT_POLICIES_pre {
    }

    chain nat_OUTPUT_POLICIES_post {
    }

    chain filter_PREROUTING {
        type filter hook prerouting priority filter + 10; policy accept;
        icmpv6 type { nd-router-advert, nd-neighbor-solicit } accept
        meta nfproto ipv6 fib saddr . mark . iif oif missing drop
    }

    chain filter_INPUT {
        type filter hook input priority filter + 10; policy accept;
        ct state { established, related } accept
        ct status dnat accept
        iifname "lo" accept
        ct state invalid drop
        jump filter_INPUT_ZONES
        reject with icmpx admin-prohibited
    }

    chain filter_FORWARD {
        type filter hook forward priority filter + 10; policy accept;
        ct state { established, related } accept
        ct status dnat accept
        iifname "lo" accept
        ct state invalid drop
        ip6 daddr { ::/96, ::ffff:0.0.0.0/96, 2002::/24, 2002:a00::/24, 2002:7f00::/24, 2002:a9fe::/32, 2002:ac10::/28, 2002:c0a8::/32, 2002:e000::/19 } reject with icmpv6 addr-unreachable
        jump filter_FORWARD_ZONES
        reject with icmpx admin-prohibited
    }

    chain filter_OUTPUT {
        type filter hook output priority filter + 10; policy accept;
        ct state { established, related } accept
        oifname "lo" accept
        ip6 daddr { ::/96, ::ffff:0.0.0.0/96, 2002::/24, 2002:a00::/24, 2002:7f00::/24, 2002:a9fe::/32, 2002:ac10::/28, 2002:c0a8::/32, 2002:e000::/19 } reject with icmpv6 addr-unreachable
        jump filter_OUTPUT_POLICIES_pre
        jump filter_OUTPUT_POLICIES_post
    }

    chain filter_INPUT_POLICIES_pre {
        jump filter_IN_policy_allow-host-ipv6
    }

    chain filter_INPUT_ZONES {
        iifname "br0" goto filter_IN_FedoraWorkstation
        iifname "eth11" goto filter_IN_FedoraWorkstation
        iifname "eth01" goto filter_IN_FedoraWorkstation
        iifname "vpn0" goto filter_IN_FedoraWorkstation
        iifname "ens1f1" goto filter_IN_FedoraWorkstation
        iifname "docker0" goto filter_IN_docker
        goto filter_IN_FedoraWorkstation
    }

    chain filter_INPUT_POLICIES_post {
    }

    chain filter_FORWARD_POLICIES_pre {
    }

    chain filter_FORWARD_ZONES {
        iifname "br0" goto filter_FWD_FedoraWorkstation
        iifname "eth11" goto filter_FWD_FedoraWorkstation
        iifname "eth01" goto filter_FWD_FedoraWorkstation
        iifname "vpn0" goto filter_FWD_FedoraWorkstation
        iifname "ens1f1" goto filter_FWD_FedoraWorkstation
        iifname "docker0" goto filter_FWD_docker
        goto filter_FWD_FedoraWorkstation
    }

    chain filter_FORWARD_POLICIES_post {
    }

    chain filter_OUTPUT_POLICIES_pre {
    }

    chain filter_OUTPUT_POLICIES_post {
    }

    chain filter_IN_FedoraWorkstation {
        jump filter_INPUT_POLICIES_pre
        jump filter_IN_FedoraWorkstation_pre
        jump filter_IN_FedoraWorkstation_log
        jump filter_IN_FedoraWorkstation_deny
        jump filter_IN_FedoraWorkstation_allow
        jump filter_IN_FedoraWorkstation_post
        jump filter_INPUT_POLICIES_post
        meta l4proto { icmp, ipv6-icmp } accept
        reject with icmpx admin-prohibited
    }

    chain filter_IN_FedoraWorkstation_pre {
    }

    chain filter_IN_FedoraWorkstation_log {
    }

    chain filter_IN_FedoraWorkstation_deny {
    }

    chain filter_IN_FedoraWorkstation_allow {
        ip6 daddr fe80::/64 udp dport 546 ct state { new, untracked } accept
        tcp dport 22 ct state { new, untracked } accept
        udp dport 137 ct helper set "helper-netbios-ns-udp"
        udp dport 137 ct state { new, untracked } accept
        udp dport 138 ct state { new, untracked } accept
        ip daddr 224.0.0.251 udp dport 5353 ct state { new, untracked } accept
        ip6 daddr ff02::fb udp dport 5353 ct state { new, untracked } accept
        udp dport 1025-65535 ct state { new, untracked } accept
        tcp dport 1025-65535 ct state { new, untracked } accept
    }

    chain filter_IN_FedoraWorkstation_post {
    }

    chain nat_POST_FedoraWorkstation {
        jump nat_POSTROUTING_POLICIES_pre
        jump nat_POST_FedoraWorkstation_pre
        jump nat_POST_FedoraWorkstation_log
        jump nat_POST_FedoraWorkstation_deny
        jump nat_POST_FedoraWorkstation_allow
        jump nat_POST_FedoraWorkstation_post
        jump nat_POSTROUTING_POLICIES_post
    }

    chain nat_POST_FedoraWorkstation_pre {
    }

    chain nat_POST_FedoraWorkstation_log {
    }

    chain nat_POST_FedoraWorkstation_deny {
    }

    chain nat_POST_FedoraWorkstation_allow {
    }

    chain nat_POST_FedoraWorkstation_post {
    }

    chain filter_FWD_FedoraWorkstation {
        jump filter_FORWARD_POLICIES_pre
        jump filter_FWD_FedoraWorkstation_pre
        jump filter_FWD_FedoraWorkstation_log
        jump filter_FWD_FedoraWorkstation_deny
        jump filter_FWD_FedoraWorkstation_allow
        jump filter_FWD_FedoraWorkstation_post
        jump filter_FORWARD_POLICIES_post
        reject with icmpx admin-prohibited
    }

    chain filter_FWD_FedoraWorkstation_pre {
    }

    chain filter_FWD_FedoraWorkstation_log {
    }

    chain filter_FWD_FedoraWorkstation_deny {
    }

    chain filter_FWD_FedoraWorkstation_allow {
    }

    chain filter_FWD_FedoraWorkstation_post {
    }

    chain nat_PRE_FedoraWorkstation {
        jump nat_PREROUTING_POLICIES_pre
        jump nat_PRE_FedoraWorkstation_pre
        jump nat_PRE_FedoraWorkstation_log
        jump nat_PRE_FedoraWorkstation_deny
        jump nat_PRE_FedoraWorkstation_allow
        jump nat_PRE_FedoraWorkstation_post
        jump nat_PREROUTING_POLICIES_post
    }

    chain nat_PRE_FedoraWorkstation_pre {
    }

    chain nat_PRE_FedoraWorkstation_log {
    }

    chain nat_PRE_FedoraWorkstation_deny {
    }

    chain nat_PRE_FedoraWorkstation_allow {
    }

    chain nat_PRE_FedoraWorkstation_post {
    }

    chain mangle_PRE_FedoraWorkstation {
        jump mangle_PREROUTING_POLICIES_pre
        jump mangle_PRE_FedoraWorkstation_pre
        jump mangle_PRE_FedoraWorkstation_log
        jump mangle_PRE_FedoraWorkstation_deny
        jump mangle_PRE_FedoraWorkstation_allow
        jump mangle_PRE_FedoraWorkstation_post
        jump mangle_PREROUTING_POLICIES_post
    }

    chain mangle_PRE_FedoraWorkstation_pre {
    }

    chain mangle_PRE_FedoraWorkstation_log {
    }

    chain mangle_PRE_FedoraWorkstation_deny {
    }

    chain mangle_PRE_FedoraWorkstation_allow {
    }

    chain mangle_PRE_FedoraWorkstation_post {
    }

    chain filter_IN_policy_allow-host-ipv6 {
        jump filter_IN_policy_allow-host-ipv6_pre
        jump filter_IN_policy_allow-host-ipv6_log
        jump filter_IN_policy_allow-host-ipv6_deny
        jump filter_IN_policy_allow-host-ipv6_allow
        jump filter_IN_policy_allow-host-ipv6_post
    }

    chain filter_IN_policy_allow-host-ipv6_pre {
    }

    chain filter_IN_policy_allow-host-ipv6_log {
    }

    chain filter_IN_policy_allow-host-ipv6_deny {
    }

    chain filter_IN_policy_allow-host-ipv6_allow {
        icmpv6 type nd-neighbor-advert accept
        icmpv6 type nd-neighbor-solicit accept
        icmpv6 type nd-router-advert accept
        icmpv6 type nd-redirect accept
    }

    chain filter_IN_policy_allow-host-ipv6_post {
    }

    chain nat_PRE_policy_allow-host-ipv6 {
        jump nat_PRE_policy_allow-host-ipv6_pre
        jump nat_PRE_policy_allow-host-ipv6_log
        jump nat_PRE_policy_allow-host-ipv6_deny
        jump nat_PRE_policy_allow-host-ipv6_allow
        jump nat_PRE_policy_allow-host-ipv6_post
    }

    chain nat_PRE_policy_allow-host-ipv6_pre {
    }

    chain nat_PRE_policy_allow-host-ipv6_log {
    }

    chain nat_PRE_policy_allow-host-ipv6_deny {
    }

    chain nat_PRE_policy_allow-host-ipv6_allow {
    }

    chain nat_PRE_policy_allow-host-ipv6_post {
    }

    chain mangle_PRE_policy_allow-host-ipv6 {
        jump mangle_PRE_policy_allow-host-ipv6_pre
        jump mangle_PRE_policy_allow-host-ipv6_log
        jump mangle_PRE_policy_allow-host-ipv6_deny
        jump mangle_PRE_policy_allow-host-ipv6_allow
        jump mangle_PRE_policy_allow-host-ipv6_post
    }

    chain mangle_PRE_policy_allow-host-ipv6_pre {
    }

    chain mangle_PRE_policy_allow-host-ipv6_log {
    }

    chain mangle_PRE_policy_allow-host-ipv6_deny {
    }

    chain mangle_PRE_policy_allow-host-ipv6_allow {
    }

    chain mangle_PRE_policy_allow-host-ipv6_post {
    }

    chain filter_IN_docker {
        jump filter_INPUT_POLICIES_pre
        jump filter_IN_docker_pre
        jump filter_IN_docker_log
        jump filter_IN_docker_deny
        jump filter_IN_docker_allow
        jump filter_IN_docker_post
        jump filter_INPUT_POLICIES_post
        accept
    }

    chain filter_IN_docker_pre {
    }

    chain filter_IN_docker_log {
    }

    chain filter_IN_docker_deny {
    }

    chain filter_IN_docker_allow {
    }

    chain filter_IN_docker_post {
    }

    chain nat_POST_docker {
        jump nat_POSTROUTING_POLICIES_pre
        jump nat_POST_docker_pre
        jump nat_POST_docker_log
        jump nat_POST_docker_deny
        jump nat_POST_docker_allow
        jump nat_POST_docker_post
        jump nat_POSTROUTING_POLICIES_post
    }

    chain nat_POST_docker_pre {
    }

    chain nat_POST_docker_log {
    }

    chain nat_POST_docker_deny {
    }

    chain nat_POST_docker_allow {
    }

    chain nat_POST_docker_post {
    }

    chain filter_FWD_docker {
        jump filter_FORWARD_POLICIES_pre
        jump filter_FWD_docker_pre
        jump filter_FWD_docker_log
        jump filter_FWD_docker_deny
        jump filter_FWD_docker_allow
        jump filter_FWD_docker_post
        jump filter_FORWARD_POLICIES_post
        accept
    }

    chain filter_FWD_docker_pre {
    }

    chain filter_FWD_docker_log {
    }

    chain filter_FWD_docker_deny {
    }

    chain filter_FWD_docker_allow {
        oifname "docker0" accept
    }

    chain filter_FWD_docker_post {
    }

    chain nat_PRE_docker {
        jump nat_PREROUTING_POLICIES_pre
        jump nat_PRE_docker_pre
        jump nat_PRE_docker_log
        jump nat_PRE_docker_deny
        jump nat_PRE_docker_allow
        jump nat_PRE_docker_post
        jump nat_PREROUTING_POLICIES_post
    }

    chain nat_PRE_docker_pre {
    }

    chain nat_PRE_docker_log {
    }

    chain nat_PRE_docker_deny {
    }

    chain nat_PRE_docker_allow {
    }

    chain nat_PRE_docker_post {
    }

    chain mangle_PRE_docker {
        jump mangle_PREROUTING_POLICIES_pre
        jump mangle_PRE_docker_pre
        jump mangle_PRE_docker_log
        jump mangle_PRE_docker_deny
        jump mangle_PRE_docker_allow
        jump mangle_PRE_docker_post
        jump mangle_PREROUTING_POLICIES_post
    }

    chain mangle_PRE_docker_pre {
    }

    chain mangle_PRE_docker_log {
    }

    chain mangle_PRE_docker_deny {
    }

    chain mangle_PRE_docker_allow {
    }

    chain mangle_PRE_docker_post {
    }
}
table ip nat {
    chain DOCKER {
        iifname "docker0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 return
    }

    chain POSTROUTING {
        type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
        oifname != "docker0" ip saddr 172.17.0.0/16 counter packets 4 bytes 230 masquerade 
    }

    chain PREROUTING {
        type nat hook prerouting priority dstnat; policy accept;
        fib daddr type local counter packets 22340 bytes 10759965 jump DOCKER
    }

    chain OUTPUT {
        type nat hook output priority -100; policy accept;
        ip daddr != 127.0.0.0/8 fib daddr type local counter packets 42 bytes 3674 jump DOCKER
    }
}
table ip filter {
    chain DOCKER {
    }

    chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 {
        iifname "docker0" oifname != "docker0" counter packets 15 bytes 956 jump DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
        counter packets 98 bytes 8062 return
    }

    chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 {
        oifname "docker0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 drop
        counter packets 15 bytes 956 return
    }

    chain FORWARD {
        type filter hook forward priority filter; policy drop;
        counter packets 98 bytes 8062 jump DOCKER-USER
        counter packets 98 bytes 8062 jump DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
        oifname "docker0" ct state related,established counter packets 13 bytes 1226 accept
        oifname "docker0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump DOCKER
        iifname "docker0" oifname != "docker0" counter packets 15 bytes 956 accept
        iifname "docker0" oifname "docker0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        iifname "br0" counter packets 70 bytes 5880 accept
        counter packets 0 bytes 0
        counter packets 0 bytes 0
        counter packets 0 bytes 0
        counter packets 0 bytes 0
        counter packets 0 bytes 0
        counter packets 0 bytes 0
        iifname "br0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        iifname "br0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
    }

    chain DOCKER-USER {
        counter packets 98 bytes 8062 return
    }
}
```

## so I guess this is related somehow to ip filter below

```bash
➜ sudo nft list table ip filter   
table ip filter {
    chain DOCKER {
    }

    chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 {
        iifname "docker0" oifname != "docker0" counter packets 15 bytes 956 jump DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
        counter packets 98 bytes 8062 return
    }

    chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 {
        oifname "docker0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 drop
        counter packets 15 bytes 956 return
    }

    chain FORWARD {
        type filter hook forward priority filter; policy drop;
        counter packets 98 bytes 8062 jump DOCKER-USER
        counter packets 98 bytes 8062 jump DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
        oifname "docker0" ct state related,established counter packets 13 bytes 1226 accept
        oifname "docker0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump DOCKER
        iifname "docker0" oifname != "docker0" counter packets 15 bytes 956 accept
        iifname "docker0" oifname "docker0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        iifname "br0" counter packets 70 bytes 5880 accept
        counter packets 0 bytes 0
        counter packets 0 bytes 0
        counter packets 0 bytes 0
        counter packets 0 bytes 0
        counter packets 0 bytes 0
        counter packets 0 bytes 0
        iifname "br0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        iifname "br0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
    }

    chain DOCKER-USER {
        counter packets 98 bytes 8062 return
    }
}
```

Comment: @A.B added output for the first command, but second failed with `➜ sudo nft list table ip firewalld  
Error: No such file or directory
list table ip firewalld
              ^^^^^^^^`

Comment: I have posted above entire set of riles in the nft @A.B

Comment: @A.B reading some additional documentation on the matter! Thank you for the very detailed answer and diagram - very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll limit my references to IPv4 (IPv6 or ARP are also affected, but IPv6 isn't used by OP and no default firewall for ARP exists).

Docker [relies on and loads](https://github.com/moby/libnetwork/blob/64b7a4574d1426139437d20e81c0b6d391130ec8/drivers/bridge/bridge.go#L383) the kernel module [`br_netfilter`](https://ebtables.netfilter.org/documentation/bridge-nf.html) for proper control of container isolation, even between two containers in the same LAN.

This makes Netfilter call IPv4 hooks for *bridged* frames of type IPv4. While this is documented for *iptables*, *nftables* uses the same Netfilter API and its IPv4 hooks (thus family `ip` for pure IPv4 and family `inet` for hybrid IPv4+IPv6) are affected the same. The result is described with this schematic:

[image: Packet flow in Netfilter and General Networking]

With `br_netfilter` loaded, *iptables* and *nftables* IPv4 components (small green boxes) normally used in the IPv4 network layer (green boxes in green field) are also used for the bridging link layer case (green boxes in blue field).

So a bridged *frame* becomes firewalled by *iptables*'s filter/FORWARD chain. And OP did something that's normally not needed (without `br_netfilter` bridged frames never traverse iptables' filter/FORWARD):

> ```
> sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i br0 -j ACCEPT
> ```

This allows to bypass the default DROP policy installed by Docker in the FORWARD chain and which now applies to *bridged frames*. Actually when Docker is around, this rule should be inserted (rather than added) to the `DOCKER-USER` chain instead with:

```
sudo iptables -I DOCKER-USER -i br0 -j ACCEPT
```

But it's also firewalled by any additional hook doing the same: here pure *nftables* installed by Firewalld, using the `inet firewalld` table. This part rejects the bridged packets:

```
table inet firewalld {

...

    chain filter_FORWARD {
        type filter hook forward priority filter + 10; policy accept;

...

        reject with icmpx admin-prohibited
    }
```

In the end the packet is accepted in the first (*iptables*) forward hook, but gets rejected in the second (Firewalld's *nftables*) forward hook.

Here, simply doing (in addition to OP's `iptables` command) this as root user, using *nftables*:

```
nft insert rule inet firewalld filter_FORWARD iifname br0 oifname br0 accept
```

will also allow the frame in this second hook until the rule gets overwritten. The setup should instead be added in Firewalld's own configuration.

Testing on a Fedora 37 container whith Firewalld changed to OP's settings (and module `br_netfilter` loaded on host), here's how to get Firewalld to add a forward accept rule for the `br0` interface and the ping working:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=FedoraWorkstation --remove-interface=br0
firewall-cmd --zone=FedoraWorkstation --remove-interface=br0 --permanent
firewall-cmd --zone=trusted --add-interface=br0
firewall-cmd --zone=trusted --add-interface=br0 --permanent
```

Probably some custom zone with adequate security rules should be used instead.

Some Stack Exchange links where I made answers to related Docker issues:

[1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/572022/linux-bridge-for-virtual-machines-not-forwarding-ip-packets-but-is-forwarding-a) [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/719112/why-do-net-bridge-bridge-nf-call-arp-ip-ip6tables-default-to-1) [3](https://serverfault.com/questions/963759/docker-breaks-libvirt-bridge-network) [4](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/657545/nftables-whitelisting-docker)